# HTML/Java: collapse or hide all boxes

Tags: javascript, html, hide

I've got a HTML page with a small snippet to collapse or hide information. Now I want to create a certain link where I can hide or collapse all. But I am a neaby in JS and have no idee how to solve this.

Could you please help me?

Here is my page code:

```css
/* main text and body formatting */
body {font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial;}
h1 {background-color: #87CEFA; font-variant: small-caps;}
h2 {background-color: #DFE9F5; font-variant: small-caps;}
div.info {background-color: #F5EDDF;}
img.button {height: 18px; width: auto;}
   
/* main link formatting */
a:link{color: #1A55B2;}
a:visited{color: #1A55B2;}
a:hover{color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #1A55B2; text-decoration:none;}
a:active{color: #1A55B2;}
   
/* infobox link formatting */
a.info:link{color: #1A55B2; text-decoration:none; font-weight: bold;}
a.info:visited{color: #1A55B2; text-decoration:none;}
a.info:hover{color: #1A55B2; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-bottom:1px dotted;}
a.info:active{color: #1A55B2; text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="./help.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
       <!-- script to collapse or hide infobox link -->
  <script language="javascript"> 
   function toggle(elementId) {
    var ele = document.getElementById(elementId);
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
    ele.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    }
   }
  </script> 
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Index</h1>
  <ul>
   <li><a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle('toggleMenu');" class="info">menu</a>
    <div id="toggleMenu" style="display: none" href="javascript:toggle();">
     <ol>
      <li>    
       <a href="menu_new_order.html">new order</a>
      </li>
      <li>    
       <a href="menu_open_order.html">open order</a>
      </li>
      <li>    
       <a href="menu_duplicate_order.html">duplicate order</a>
      </li>
     </ol>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li><a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle('toggleGeneral');" class="info">general</a>
    <div id="toggleGeneral" style="display: none" href="javascript:toggle();">
     <ol>
      <li>    
       <a href="general_shortcuts.html">shortcuts / hotkeys</a>
      </li>
     </ol>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li><a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle('toggleOrder');" class="info">order</a>
    <div id="toggleOrder" style="display: none" href="javascript:toggle();">
     <ol>
      <li>    
       <a href="order_order_information.html">order information</a>
      </li>
     </ol>
    </div>
   </li>
  </ul> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "all" ?

Comment: In the current state only the unsorted list is displayed and when I click on a link in this list a `<ol>`-list is displayed. I have to selecet every link in the structure level to see the howl structure.
With "all" I mean that all links in the first level of the structure shell be expanded

Comment: So you want to open the 3 lists at the same time ?

Comment: Correct and collapse them at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I created a `toggleAll()` function for show/hide all the menus and changed `href` attribute. See below.

```html
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="./help.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <!-- script to collapse or hide infobox link -->
        <script language="javascript"> 
            function toggle(elementId) {
                var ele = document.getElementById(elementId);
                if(ele.style.display == "block") {
                ele.style.display = "none";
                }
                else {
                ele.style.display = "block";
                }
            }
            function toggleAll(){
                document.getElementById("toggleMenu");
                document.getElementById("toggleGeneral");
                document.getElementById("toggleOrder");
            }
        </script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Index</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggleAll();" class="info">menu</a>
                <div id="toggleMenu" style="display: none">
                    <ol>
                        <li>                
                            <a href="menu_new_order.html">new order</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>                
                            <a href="menu_open_order.html">open order</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>                
                            <a href="menu_duplicate_order.html">duplicate order</a>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggleAll();" class="info">general</a>
                <div id="toggleGeneral" style="display: none">
                    <ol>
                        <li>                
                            <a href="general_shortcuts.html">shortcuts / hotkeys</a>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggleAll();" class="info">order</a>
                <div id="toggleOrder" style="display: none">
                    <ol>
                        <li>                
                            <a href="order_order_information.html">order information</a>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </body>
</html>
```

You can also clear the HTML code by putting your styles in CSS file like so:

```
#toggleMenu, #toggleGeneral, #toggleOrder {
    display: none;
}
```